# How Does UEFI Display Work Without GOP and UGA?

Tags: uefi, gop

How to image via a UEFI bootloader/OS without GOP and UGA (+CSM disable)?

I have Lenovo V570c computer without UEFI GOP and UGA. Legacy calls like INT 10 don't work when CSM is off. How then is the image rendered? Also, rEFInd/Clover/OpenCore says I output video with GOP, but there is no for Intel HD Graphics 3000 UEFI GOP in BIOS.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What makes you say that your system doesn't have GOP?

Comment: @Nassbirne There is no GOP driver.  You can download and review the 44CN43WW version BIOS file.